# How did they transform this equation $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n-k}=n \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{1}{l}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How did they transform the left side to become the right side?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n-k}=n \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{1}{l}$$

It seems like they used $l:=n-k$, but then we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n-k}= n \sum_{l=n-1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{l}$$ because $l=n-k \iff k=n-l$.

Comment: For what it's worth: although my answer is *valid*, Ak19's answer is clearly more elegant and therefore (arguably) *better*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you've guessed it that you should substitute $l= n-k$.

But the limits are,
$k=0 \Rightarrow l = n-k = n-0=n$
$k=n-1 \Rightarrow l = n-k = n-(n-1)=1$

The sum thus becomes,

$$\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{n}{l}  = n\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{1}{l}$$

Answer (score 1):

On the LHS, $n$, which is a constant, can be transferred to outside
the summation.  The LHS now becomes

$n \times \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ~\frac{1}{n-k}.$

Then, the LHS summation is re-indexed from $0 \leftrightarrow (n-1)$
to $1 \leftrightarrow n$.  Thus, the LHS now becomes

$n \times \sum_{k=1}^{n} ~\frac{1}{n-(k-1)}.$

The final conversion is simply an acknowledgement that the following
two sets are identical:

$\{[n - (1-1)], [n - (2-1)], \cdots, [n - (n-1)]\}$ and
$\{1,2, \cdots, n\}.$

Answer (score 1):

> We can transform the left-hand side as follows:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}}&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-(n-1-k)}\tag{1}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $n$ and change the order of summation $k\to n-1-k$.
- In (2) we simplify the expression.
- In (3) we shift the index by one to start with $k=1$.